# Is there a "greater than about" symbol?

Tags: inequality, notation, approximation

To indicate approximate equality, one can use ≃, ≅, ~, ♎, or ≒.

I need to indicate an approximate inequality. Specifically, I know A is greater than a quantity of approximately B.

Is there a way to succinctly express this mathematically?

Comment: Can you give more details?

Comment: If you like. I know anecdotally that steam plumes are visible on the fumarolic ice towers of Mt Erebus when the relative humidity goes above something like 20%.

Answer (score 79, accepted):

LaTeX has the symbols `\lessapprox` ($\lessapprox$) and `\gtrapprox` ($\gtrapprox$).

Incidentally, a long time ago I came across this awesome [Short Math Guide for $\LaTeX$](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf), a free pdf by the American Mathematical Society. Well-worth keeping it close by.

Comment: Brilliant! I consistently underestimate LaTeX... and unicode for that matter...

Comment: So I guess we'd use this if we knew our approximation wasn't very good, or if we couldn't reliably bound it?

Comment: @foobarbecue Glad you like it. I'd appreciate if you could accept my answer, if you're so inclined. Thanks.

Comment: Been trying to, but there's a 10 minute minimum waiting time it seems. Four minutes to go.

Comment: This symbol is not very common in my experience, so I would be careful to explain what you mean by it.

Comment: In addition, when you want only one tilde symbol, use \lessim and \gtrsim

Comment: Since the link for this math guide appears to no longer work, I here provide a link to the same document that does work (as of 1 March 2017) http://www.math.hkbu.edu.hk/TeX/short-math-guide.pdf

Comment: @Wouter that should be \lesssim with a triple s

Comment: These symbols are not available in vanilla latex; you need to use the package `amssymb`.

Comment: The link in the answer requires you to connect to a server. What's going on?

Comment: @DavidKetcheson one can just paste the symbols: ⪆, $\text{⪆}$

Comment: Pasting  ⪆ or ⪆ produces "Unicode character  ⪆ (U+2A86) not set up for use with LaTeX" for me.